# How to disable pubkey algorithms in python sshtunnel

Tags: python, paramiko, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

I'm having trouble establishing an sshtunnel connection because the server does not support the rsa-sha2-512 pubkey algorithm. I can't change anything on the server. I am able to connect using paramiko but only if I use the disable_algorithms configuration argument. When I am using sshtunnel, I can't figure out how to adjust the configuration for the paramiko disable_algorithms.

```
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (REMOTE_SSH_IP, 22),
    ssh_username='username',
    ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080)
) as tunnel:
    print('DONE')
```

If I use paramiko to open an ssh session to the same machine, using the same public key, I am able to connect without an issue BUT only when I set the disabled_algorithms in the SSHClient config.

```
disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"])
```

If I could set the same disabled_algorithms inside sshtunnel somehow then I think that would solve my problem. I have tried using ~/.ssh/config however sshtunnel does not seem to honor it, even when I set the path in the open_tunnel configuration. I still get the same errors. `ssh_config_file="~/.ssh/config"`

Thanks in advance.

python 3.10.2 stdout:

```
ERROR:sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder:Could not open connection to gateway
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blah/Files/Devel/TXPro/inventory/inventory/cli/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
  File "/Users/blah/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1608, in __enter__
    self.start()
  File "/Users/blah/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1331, in start
    self._raise(BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError,
  File "/Users/blah/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1174, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

paramiko 2.9.2 debug:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Server did not send a server-sig-algs list; defaulting to our first preferred algo ('rsa-sha2-512')
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:NOTE: you may use the 'disabled_algorithms' SSHClient/Transport init kwarg to disable that or other algorithms if your server does not support them!
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

The sshd logs - OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013:

```
sshd[32307]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for <HIDDEN> [HIDDEN] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
sshd[32307]: userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
sshd[32307]: Connection closed by <HIDDEN> [preauth]
```

~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
        HostbasedAcceptedAlgorithms -rsa-sha2-256,-rsa-sha2-512
        HostKeyAlgorithms -rsa-sha2-256,-rsa-sha2-512
        PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms -rsa-sha2-256,-rsa-sha2-512
```

Comment: did you try configure the algorithm in sshconfig file? because `sshtunnel` might reuse the config files.

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you for that suggestion. I tried adding `HostKeyAlgorithms -rsa-sha2-256,-rsa-sha2-512` to my `.ssh/config` but it doesn't seem to be read by `sshtunnel`. I can ssh just fine from the command line to the server in question, using the same private key that I'm using in my script, just not from python using sshtunnel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest version of paramiko library e.g. *paramiko~=2.11.0*, there is an issue: [RSA key being treated as a DSA key](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1839). The issue is solved using a lower version of the library e.g. *paramiko~=2.8.1*, without using the ssh config or disabled_algorithms flag.